# cmder/git showing (master -> origin) as branch instead of (master)

Tags: git, cmder

I was following a tutorial on how to setup gut for a project and after `git init` cmder is showing me (master -> origin) instead of (master) as the current branch.

What does that mean? Anything I should be worried about before continuing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

origin is a default name used for the remote repository you cloned from and is set up by git, nothing to worry about.